# Read variable after connecting to remote server through ssh in shell script

Tags: shell

I have requirement. In my shell script i am connecting to remote server as ssh after connecting I want to read a variable in remote server.

Could some one please help me on this?

Comment: Please post your shell script.

Comment: ssh -T ${host_name} "bash -s" --< /home/oracle/raj/test.sh ${db_name}
part of the main script
here is in test.sh i am trying to read variable which i am unable to

Comment: Add this in your question by clicking on `edit`.